# Treeview selectedItem highlight on startup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a treeview in my xaml as below. I use the selected item by using interactivity and bind the event.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TreeTemplate">
        <TreeView Name="TreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction
                        Command="{Binding SetSelectedItemCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=TreeView}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TreeView>
    </DataTemplate>
```

This all works very well except when by application loads for the first time. Even if SelectedItem property is set on startup, the treeview does not show the item highlighted unless a mouse event is fired which causes SelectedItemChanged event.
Any ideas as as to how can I do this?

My datacontext is in code behind of the xaml

```
        myView = new MyViewModel();    
        this.DataContext = myView;

        InitializeComponent();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TreeTemplate">
    <TreeView Name="TreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction
                    Command="{Binding SetSelectedItemCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=TreeView}"/>

             <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction
                    Command="{Binding SetSelectedItemCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=TreeView}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TreeView>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Its a very good suggestion. I din't think of it before but a second problem is that 'Loaded' is called before I am able to set my property.

Comment: Loaded is called after your ViewModels constructor, in your Viewmodels constructor you should finish all your bindings.

Comment: I am loading a file in my constructor. The properties are loaded depending on the file. Before the code can set the property, the loaded event is called and at that time the property is null

Comment: How do you define your datacontext for  view ?

Comment: Updated in the question

Comment: According to your code, your viewModel should be constructed before your UI is loaded, if you set some break points at both your ViewModel constructor and the Loaded event, then you can see which one is called first. I still thing something else is wrong